# angular 4 jquery click event not working inside http get

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the code I used. Here after the php call success I triggered the click event. But it is not working inside hte http get. If I place this outside the http method it is working.

In componenet.html

```
 <a #myDiv id="anchorID" href="{{details.url}}&a={{affid}}&b={{sid}}&c={{ordid}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

In component.ts

```
this.http.get(this.apiurl+'api/insertorder.phpumid="+this.loginid).subscribe(data=>{
          var jsonData = data.json();    
          let urlpass = jsonData.url;
          this.ordid = jsonData.orderid;
          $("#anchorID")[0].click();

          },error => {
          console.log('error in sub');
          console.log(error);
          });
```

What is wrong with this. I need to call this after this success.

If i use `window.open(urlpass,'_blank');` then it creates the popup blocker issue. Please help to fix this.

Comment: Are you trying to open a link outside of your angular application?

Comment: Yes. Like http://google.com. It shows popup blocker issue

Answer (score 1):

Not only using JQuery with Angular is bad practice, but you even have use local variables inside your template to let Angular do it.

Try this instead.

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') div: ElementRef;
```

And replace your JQuery code with

```
this.div.nativeElement.click();
```

And for your issue, it probably means that your HTTP call didn't succeed. Did it ?

Comment: I am new to angular. It shows an error as "declaration expected" here div: ElementRef; I already import import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
 Whats wrong here

Comment: You didn't import `ViewChild`

Comment: It shows 'div' as unused label. I imported this too

Comment: I don't know what you did else, because it should work. Could you update your question with your new code ?

Comment: Ya, Its worrking now. My mistake. Is there any way to fix the popup blocker. It triggered the click event now. But the page not opened due to popup blocker. If i use id.click directly popup locker issue is rectified

Comment: This is only user-related, if he doesn't want to open pop-ups then you can't force him, otherwise we would be invaded with ads :)